# SQL Server to Oracle Connection

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, linked-server

I'm trying to access an Oracle Database from MS SQL Server. I installed a local Oracle DB and tried [this](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/connecting-sql-server-and-oracle-using-linked-servers) and everything worked OK.

But when I try to connect to a remote system (ie. an Oracle DB on another computer) it shows an error saying "ORA-01017 invalid username/password; logon denied".

I can connect to that computer with SQL Developer (with same user/pass).

What am I missing?

====================

Update 1:

Results of execute_sp_helplinkedsrvlogin :

```
Linked Server     LocalLogin     Is self Mapping     Remote Login
--------------    ----------     ---------------     -------------
192.168.0.56      sa             0                   sa
```

which is correct (target username is sa).

==========================

Update 2 :

I can connect to that database with sqlplus with same username and password, even add and remove data.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your Oracle TNS service name points to the correct server and instance name?

Comment: I did and I will again tommorow , but if that was the problem then the IDE (sql developer) would have the same problem too, right?

Comment: Perhaps...It might be very well be a permission issue. But, without looking at how your linked server is setup, it would be hard to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: You can try to execute the sp_helplinkedsrvlogin stored proc to ensure the login information is setup correctly.

Comment: @Rookie13 I edited the post with the result of SP.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake. oracle base was addressed incorreclty when installing oracle client. thus there was two different tnsnames.ora files and net configuration assisstant (which I used to test) used a different file from what oracle (and SSMS) were using.

Comment: I had a initial thought that it might be something to do with the tnsnames.ora file. Well, that wasn't too bad, was it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in your SSMS:

```
execute sp_helplinkedsrvlogin
```

This should return a result indicating if a remote login has been setup for each linked server. If a remote login is not setup for your linked server, go to properties page for that linked server to add a remote login.

[image: addremotelogin_linkedserver]